# How to set names for by argument in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I don't want to use `setNames` function, but do it in the statement:

```
iris2 <- data.table(iris)
iris2[,.(value = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = "Species"]
```

For example i want have names: `value` and `group`.

PS:
this is crazy! Using `agregate` cost 1200 ms. Doint the same with `data.table` cost now 30ms.!!! (on another dataset, my own big one)

Comment: You meant `iris2[,.(value = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = .(group = Species)]`

Comment: please answer I want to give ya a plus. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like we place the `j` inside the `.()`, the `by` arguments can be placed like that and named

```
iris2[, .(value = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = .(group = Species)]
```